# How to edit a row on click of a button in angular ui-grid?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I'm getting many examples for editting a cell but no example for editting a row. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the scope of ui-grid to call method from ui-grid column

```
<button ng-click='grid.appScope.readMore(row.entity)'></button>
```

define that method in your controller like

```
 $scope.readMore = function(rowData){
    console.log(rowData)
   }
```

I hope it will help you ... :)

Comment: Thank you @mayank  but i'm already getting this, I want to make all the cells as text box in the row. If I'm having 3 cells in the row then there should be 3 text boxes in the cells indicating the edit.

Comment: $scope.Edit = function(row) {
            var index = $scope.gridOptions.data.indexOf(row.entity);
            $scope.gridOptions.data[index].firstName = '<input type="text">';
          $scope.gridOptions.data[index].lastName = '<input type="text">';
            $scope.gridOptions.data[index].phoneNumber = '<input type="text">';
          
        };

Comment: @kirti can you make this on fiddle so that i can change it